# How to add php form validation with ajax error handling

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How can I add validation and php error handling with ajax. Now the success message come correctly but how can I implement error message on it? I might need to add some php validation please help.

**Here is my JS.**

```
 $('#edit_user_form').bind('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();// using this page stop being refreshing 
   $.ajax({
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    type: $(this).attr('method'),
    url: $(this).attr('action'), 

    success: function () {
     $(".msg-ok").css("display", "block");
     $(".msg-ok-text").html("Profile Updated Successfully!!");
    },
     error: function() {
     //Error Message          
    }  
  });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
require_once 'db_connect.php';
if($_POST) {
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $index_no = $_POST['index_no'];
    $contact = $_POST['contact'];

    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $sql  = "UPDATE members SET fname = '$fname', lname = '$lname', index_no = '$index_no', contact = '$contact' WHERE id = {$id}";
    if($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "<p>Succcessfully Updated</p>";
    } else {
        echo "Erorr while updating record : ". $connect->error;
    }
    $connect->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: You should return a json object instead, with some params like `{ success: true/false, errorMessage: "some message" }` and check it in your success callback for your ajax call.

Comment: this app is not for web version its an offline web app

Comment: success: function (data) {
     $(".msg-ok").css("display", "block");
     $(".msg-ok-text").html("Profile Updated Successfully!!");
    },
     error: function(errordata) {
     //Error Message          
    }

make your success and error block like this, and then through if condition you check for different messages

Comment: @MagnusEriksson can you show me an example  ?

Comment: Even so, escaping your inputs are important for more reasons than security. If a last name like: `O'Brian` gets entered, it will break your query, since the `'`-sign will mess up the quotes in the query.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks I will update it

Answer (score 1):

ajax identifies errors based of status code, your php code will always return status code 200 which is success, even when you get error in php code unless its 500 or 404. So ajax will treat response as success.

if you want to handle php error, make following changes in your code

```
<?php 
require_once 'db_connect.php';
if($_POST) {
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $index_no = $_POST['index_no'];
    $contact = $_POST['contact'];

    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $sql  = "UPDATE members SET fname = '$fname', lname = '$lname', index_no = '$index_no', contact = '$contact' WHERE id = {$id}";
    if($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "true";
    } else {
        echo "false";
    }
    $connect->close();
}
?>


$('#edit_user_form').bind('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();// using this page stop being refreshing 
   $.ajax({
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    type: $(this).attr('method'),
    url: $(this).attr('action'), 

    success: function (res) {
     if(res == 'true') {
          //success code
     } else if(res == 'false') {
          //error code
     }

    },
     error: function() {
     //Error Message          
    }  
  });
});
```

Comment: Your code works but is it possible to validate form fields

Comment: you can use bootstrap validation for the client side